# How to execute command in cloud-init

Tags: cloud-init

my cloud-init file looks like this
I want to append random 1-byte hexa

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
  - [ sudo, ip, link, set, dev, enp1s0, address, f4:f2:c7:f3:f4:"$(openssl rand -hex 1)" ]
```

no issue if i set static 6 bytes hexa like below

```
  - [ sudo, ip, link, set, dev, enp1s0, address, f4:f2:c7:f3:f4:c6 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runcmd` doesn't require every argument to be in a list.

Something like this should work:

```yaml
#cloud-config
runcmd:
  - sudo ip link set dev enp1s0 address f4:f2:c7:f3:f4:"$(openssl rand -hex 1)"
```